# Change total value of a stacked progress bar in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to change stacked progress bar maximum value. 
By default it is 100%.

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress">
   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width:20%">
    Abc
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" style="width:30%">
    dfgdf
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

In this image, I want to give maximum value 60% but it will take 100%.

Answer (score 1):

There is no property to set the maximum value; it will always be from 0 to 100. You will have to re-compute your styles to scale them to fit the 100 point scale.

If your maximum value is 60, and you want your values to fit into a 100% range, you will have to take the ratio of your value over 60 as a percent, instead of using your value directly:

```
20 / 60 * 100% = 33%
30 / 60 * 100% = 50%
```

Then your progress bar will work as expected:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 33%" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="60"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="60"></div>
</div>
```